# Django urls vs wagtail pages urls

Tags: django, wagtail

If I have a page in Wagtail with the slug of `/offers/` and I also have a Django URL for `/offers/`, which one will be used? (example code below)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('/offers', offers.as_view()),
    url(r'', include(wagtail_urls)),
]
```

Which one will take the precedence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requests for Wagtail pages are handled by the line

```
url(r'', include(wagtail_urls)),
```

in the project's URL config; if your `'home/offers'` route is above this line then it will take precedence, otherwise the Wagtail page will.